# gcc recompile "make" result no changes

Tags: makefile

i'm using cs50 appliance.

i've tried to write a new file test.c , found as long as i include int i line, it doesn't generate a new file test, if i remove that line and make again, it can generate test file. then i made changes on the test file, it still output the original file result, no reflect the new changes.

`#include <stdio.h>`
`#include <cs50.h>`

```
int
main (void)
{
printf("Number: \n");
int i = GetInt();
}
```

it was running properly before though... anyone can help please?

Comment: You'll have to provide us with more details if you expect us to be able to answer this question. For example, what does your makefile look like? Do you get any warnings or messages when running make? Please post minimal working examples of your source code and makefile which reproduce the issue you are having.

Comment: sorry i'm just start to learning programming, so i don't know where to get makefile....after running make, i get error message say unused variable i... error 1.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently your default rules for `make` run the compiler on `test.c`.
The compiler notices that you are assigning a value to variable `i`, but you never use that value in any way; it would normally report this as a warning.
Apparently either your compiler or `make` are configured in such a way that this warning becomes a fatal error to `make`.

The remedy is to use the variable.  It looks as though you need to pick up a book on the C programming language, or follow a course, if that's not what you're doing already.